# R: how to instantiate a custom split (usersplit) in rpart which requires a vector as a parameter

Tags: r, rpart

I'm inspecting tests/usersplits.R in `rpart`, trying to get my head around how to pass data to the split function.

I'm trying to instantiate a number of goodness measures which compare treatment vs control within splits.

A simple example is difference-in-difference estimate of a candidate split,

(Y_t - Y_c)_L - (Y_t - Y_c)_R
(difference between treatment and control for the left minus difference between treatment and control for the right)

I need to know whether each Y value is a treatment Y or a control.
the documentation in usersplits.R says that Y is provided in sort order of X, so I'm not sure how to pass a vector indicating treatment vs control that will split Y appropriately.

`rpart.poisson` takes a two column matrix as an input, and I've been trying to mimic that, but there's no documentation in `rpart.poisson` (I can't figure out where it creates the 'vector of goodness')

Comment: There has to a be a better solution, but could you use the `wt` (case weights) argument to pass the case/control information to these functions? (Assumes, of course, you don't need that argument already)

Comment: maybe.  I haven't thought about it. I'll look in to it.  It might work for the immediate problem, but i wouldn't want to 'overload' the parameter long term.  (in case wt needs to fill its intended purpose)

Comment: I haven't tested this, but if passing a two column matrix for y is kosher, you should be able to just do that, and do the calculations on the first column using the values in the second column as indices indicating case/control.

Comment: i'm not sure passing two columns is kosher, i just know rpart.poisson accepts a y that is n x 2, so I'm trying to figure out how that works.

Comment: You can read this material: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/usercode.pdf.
It shows how to define you own splitting function to use in the `rpart` package.